# how to make sql filters efficient php

Tags: php, mysql, filter

I have 4 filters for a catalog (name , id, date, price). Those are inputs from the user to see specific data from the database. Those 4 filters are going to produce 4^2 (16) sql_queries on php , because some of the filters may be null. Is there a better way to make queries less ?

example:

```
if(isset($_POST['filters']))
{
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $timi = $_POST['timi'];
    $employee = $_POST['dropdown_users'];
    $proion =$_POST['dropdown_proionta'];
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM id_of_orders WHERE username='$employee' AND price = '$timi' AND time = '$date' AND proion='$proion'");
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row['id_order'] . " " . $row['time'] . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify how exactly you want to filter the data?

Comment: so I want to return data even if some filter are blank.

Comment: There's only one query in that code, not 16. It's very hard to understand what the problem is.

Comment: this query will be used if all the filters are not null. for example if $date is blank i must make another query without time ='$date'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM id_of_orders WHERE 1=1";
if(!empty($employee))
  $query .= " AND username='$employee'";
if(!empty($timi))
  $query .= " AND price='$timi'";
if(!empty($date))
  $query .= " AND time='$date'";
if(!empty($proion))
  $query .= " AND proion='$proion'";
```

This way no query conditions are added for empty filters, while entered filters will be used as conditions for the results.